# MSBuild task to execute an external MSBuild file

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to set up a MSBuild file which will invoke another MSBuild file and I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve this.

We're using it in the scenario of where a build server downloads a MSBuild file which then depending on the parameters it'll execute the appropriate 2nd file.

I know I can just use the `<Exec Command="msbuild.exe ..." />` task, but that seems to be a bit of a *hacky* way to do it.

Is there an easier way to use MSBuild to execute another MSBuild file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`MSBuild task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) to build a target in another MSBuild project.

You can also put the target in an external .targets file that is imported by both MSBuild projects and use the [`CallTarget task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229474.aspx) to build it.

Update: To execute an external command, use the [`Exec task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx).

Comment: Ahh! I knew there had to be a better way. I hadn't come across the MSBuild task before :)

Comment: How do you use MSBuild Task to execute an external file?
Could you show how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

It's not just prettier to use the `<MSBuild>` task rather than `<Exec Command="msbuild.exe .."/>`. It means that the single MSBuild process knows about all the projects being built, and there's no collisions; a particular project can't be being built by two threads at once. That's usually vital if you are building with "/m".
There's some other advantages too, such as there being one set of loggers for the whole build.

Answer (score 3):

Response to Adam Oren's comment: 
Here's an example to execute an external file - in this case, it launches nunit. The %22 is for escaping, it means " so you can have spaces in your executable path.

```
<Exec Command="%22$(NUnit_Install_Directory)bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe%22 
/noshadow @(TestableAssemblies, ' ') /xml 
 $(BuildFilesPath)\NCover-NUnit-Results.xml" />
```

You don't need to use variables like I did, but I find that it makes your scripts more portable. 
$(NUnit_Install_Directory) is defined as

```
<PropertyGroup> 
   <NUnit_Install_Directory>c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.3\</NUnit_Install_Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Target Name="TA">
    <CallTarget Targets="TB"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="TB">
    <Message Text="TB..." />
</Target>
```